# Как сохранить порядок выполнения скриптов на html странице, если они подгружаются через скрипт?

Tags: javascript

В html странице через скрипт происходит динамически загрузка других скриптов на эту же страницу. Проблема состоит в том, что скрипты с атрибутом src, ссылающиеся на другие файлы выполняются позже, хотя добавляются в DOM раньше.

**index.html**

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script>

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            let headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            //Добавление 1 скрипта
            let script1 = document.createElement("script");
            script1.src = "test.js";
            headElement.appendChild(script1);

            //Добавление 2 скрипта
            let script2 = document.createElement("script");
            script2.innerHTML = "alert('Load inner script');";
            headElement.appendChild(script2);

        });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```js
  alert("load outer script");
```

В результате окна всплывают в таком порядке:
1. load inner script
2. load outer script

Что неверно, так как первый загружаемый скрипт может быть библиотекой для второго
Как заставить второй скрипт дожидаться первого, желательно без использования onload, так как я хочу загрузить несколько скриптов массивом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function() {
  let headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  //Добавление Скриптов
  let a = ["test1.js", "test2.js"].map(s => loadScript(s));
  await Promise.all(a);
  //Добавление скрипта
  let script2 = document.createElement("script");
  script2.innerHTML = "alert('Load inner script');";
  headElement.appendChild(script2);
});

function loadScript(n) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = n;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;
  });
}
```